# jQuery resize causes ugly "jump" when fired

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, web-frontend, responsiveness

I've used the [ba-resize jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/) to dynamically resize a website content div ( '#page-content' ) based on the dynamic size of a sidebar menu ( '#menu' ). The plugin allows binding resize event handlers to divs.

This is mostly working, but when the two divs adjust their sizes it causes a noticeable visual jump. See short screencast: http://recordit.co/BjIYaS36oW (no sound)

Sometimes the jump turns into a failure to load the menu completely.

How do I fix/eliminate this jumpiness on resize?

My jQuery:

```
// Adjusting content width to allow for responsive size with changing menu width
$(function(){
    $('#menu').resize(function(){
        $('#page-content').css({'width':(($(window).width()))-'#menu'});
        $("#page-content").css('marginLeft','');
        $("#page-content").css('marginRight','');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var callback = function () {
         var h = $(window).width();
         var k = $('#menu').width();
         $('#page-content').width(h-k);
      };
      $(document).ready(callback);
      $(window).resize(callback);
});
```

I suspect I have some ugly scripting here — I'm not a jQuery wizard — and I appreciate any ideas. I can share an URL to the staging website if that helps (in the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task one would normally use an event based approach.

Firstly, you could use the [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, to add a movement duration to your css resizing. The 'jump' is an attempt to do the resize in an instant, so the snap movement is unsurprising.

Then to alternate between the two events an approach would be with the [jQuery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.
Specifying two separate events: one for the altering the width properties of the menu div, and the second for removing these.

```
  jQuery(".menu_toggle").one("click", handler1);
                function handler1() {
                    //Expand Menu
                    jQuery(".menu_toggle").one("click", handler2);
                }

                function handler2() {
                    //Collapse Menu
                    jQuery(".menu_toggle").one("click", handler1);
                }
```

Comment: The reason I used the ba-resize plugin is because not all the triggers for resize are click events, there will be a third width for the menu based on css media queries (not done yet). So while I want to take your advice and use animate, I'm still not sure how. Any ideas?